# Problems giving owner role in appRegistration azure using Terraform

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I'm creating an App Registration in Azure using Terraform.

After that, I try to give owner permission to other person (myself) but it doesn't let me.

The command sequence I'm using is:

```
resource "azurerm_azuread_application" "service_principal" {
  name                       = "${var.departamentoCamel}-${var.appnameCamel}-${var.entorno}"
  homepage                   = "https://${lower("${var.appnameCamel}")}.asisa.es"
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = true
}
resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal" "service_principal" {
  application_id = "${azurerm_azuread_application.service_principal.application_id}"
}
resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password" "service_principal" {
  service_principal_id  = "${azurerm_azuread_service_principal.service_principal.id}"
  value                       = "${random_string.password.result}="
  end_date              = "2020-01-01T01:02:03Z"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "test" {
  scope                = "${azurerm_azuread_application.service_principal.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Owner"
  principal_id         = "8c7b71b3-cf32-4da5-9bbb-5e5dd249c607"
}
```

But I get the following error message:

```
* azurerm_role_assignment.test: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="MissingSubscription" Message="The request did not have a provided subscription. All requests must have an associated subscription Id."
```

Does anyone know how to give Owner role to the person with ObjectID 
8c7b71b3-cf32-4da5-9bbb-5e5dd249c607 ?

Thanks,
Juanra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `azurerm_role_assignment` is used to assigns a given Principal (User or Application) to a given Role.

The [`scope`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html#scope) should be the resource id of the azure resource under your azure subscription, the service principal belongs to Azure AD, it is not the resource in the subscription.

If you want to add owners to your service principal, it seems not support via terraform.

Workarounds:

1.Navigate to the azure portal, Azure AD -> Enterprise applications - All applications - > your service principal -> Owners -> Add.

2.Use azure powershell [`Add-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadserviceprincipalowner?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: For doing 1 you need to be an administrator in the tenant account. Or that the owner makes you owner.